# Custom button in adminhtml order view page : how to run php script on click?

Tags: php, adminhtml

I added a custom button on the adminhtml order view page but I do not manage to link it to the associated php function.

Here is the code I used in my module :

EDIT

config.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>  
        <Mine_Sitreatmodule>  
            <version>0.0.1</version>  
        </Mine_Sitreatmodule>  
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <sitreatmodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mine_Sitreatmodule</module>
                    <frontName>sitreatmodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </sitreatmodule>
        </routers>    
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sitreatmodule>
                    <file>sitreatmodule.xml</file>
                </sitreatmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>  

        <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <Mine_Sitreatmodule_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mine_Sitreatmodule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sitreatmth</method> 
                    </Mine_Sitreatmodule_Model_Observer> 
                </observers> 
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> 
        </events>

         <translate>
            <modules>
                <sitreatmodule>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mine_Sitreatmodule.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </sitreatmodule>
            </modules>
        </translate>

    </frontend>


    <adminhtml>

    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view>
            <observers>
                <sitreatmodule>
                    <class>sitreatmodule/adminhtml_observer</class>
                    <method>addPaidButton</method>
                </sitreatmodule>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    </events>

        <routers>
            <sitreatmodule>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mine_Sitreatmodule</module>
                    <frontName>sitreatmodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </sitreatmodule>
        </routers>

    </adminhtml>


    <global>
        <blocks>
            <sitreatmodule>
                <class>Mine_Sitreatmodule_Block</class>
            </sitreatmodule>

        </blocks>
        <models>
            <sitreatmodule>
                <class>Mine_Sitreatmodule_Model</class>
            </sitreatmodule>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <sitreatmodule>
                <class>Mine_Sitreatmodule_Helper</class>
            </sitreatmodule>
        </helpers>


    </global>

</config>
```

The Observer

```
<?php 
class Mine_Sitreatmodule_Model_Adminhtml_Observer 
{
    public function addPaidButton($observer) {
        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('sales_order_edit');
        if (!$block){
            return $this;
        }
        $order = Mage::registry('current_order');


        $block->addButton('cygtest_resubmit', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Paid'),
          'onclick'   => "location.href='".$block->getUrl('Sitreatmodule/Paid/gotopaid',array('order_id'=>$order->getId()))."'", 
          'class'     => ''
         ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The Controller

```
    <?php
class Mine_Sitreatmodule_Adminhtml_PaidController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

   public function indexAction()
   {
        //$this->loadLayout();
        //$this->renderLayout();
   }

   public function gotopaidAction()
    {
        echo("it works");

    }

}
?>
```

But when I click the button I get a page not found.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

**Create admin Controller file** (PaidorderController.php) at location : \app\code\local\Mine\Sitreatmodule\Paidorder\controllers\Adminhtml\

```
public function gotoPaidAction()
{
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id',false);
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);


}
```

**The Observer**

```
<?php 
class Mine_Sitreatmodule_Model_Adminhtml_Observer 
{
    public function addPaidButton($observer) {
        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('sales_order_edit');
        if (!$block){
            return $this;
        }
        $order = Mage::registry('current_order');

        $block->addButton('cygtest_resubmit', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Paid'),
          'onclick'   => "location.href='".$block->getUrl('Sitreatmodule/Paidorder/Gotopaid',array('order_id'=>$order->getId()))."'", 
          'class'     => ''
         ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I do not manage to call the controller action. I have tried several xml declaration in config.xml without success...

Comment: can you share your config.xml?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I editted the original post with the new code.

Comment: any idea ? I still haven't found...